# Alternative for Connected To Internet(), it doesn‘t work

Tags: autohotkey

this command is just invalid, it doesn‘t work.

code:

```
Internet = disconnected


Internet:
If Connected To Internet()
{
Internet = connected
}
else {
Sound beep 1000,250
Internet = disconnected
}
return

<^<!=::Msg Box internet:%internet%
```

What can I use instead of Connected to internet() function??

any answer? thanks.

also, I‘m using the current version of Auto Hot Key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<^<!=::
    If DllCall("Wininet.dll\InternetGetConnectedState", "Str", 0x40,"Int",0) 
        MsgBox, 262208, Info, Internet = connected
    else
    {
        SoundBeep 1000,250
        MsgBox,4144, Warning, Internet = disconnected
    }
return
```